# YII2 Как правильно построить запрос с joinWith?

Tags: php, sql, yii2

yii2-advanced, суть: получаю `$id`, нахожу в таблице `product_image` `'id' => $id`, и также надо найти запись из таблицы `product`, у которой должно быть `'id' => 'product_image->id'`. Найти нужно одну запись картинки и одну запись продукта.
Как это оформить?
Сделал так:

```
$model = Images::find()
            ->joinWith('products')
            ->where(['id' => $id])
            ->andWhere(['id' => 'product_id'])
            ->one();
```

но похоже что что-то не так оформил.
Думаю можно сделать 2 запроса, но тогда какой смысл от joinWith?
Можно обойтись без второго запроса и как это оформить?

2 запроса выглядят так:

```
        $model = Images::find()->where(['id' => $id])->one();
        $prod = Products::find()->where(['id' => $model->product_id])->one();
```

Связи `products` и `images`:

```
public function getProducts()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Products::className(), ['id' => 'product_id']);
}

public function getImages()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Images::className(), ['product_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Сам метод, для которого нужен запрос:

```
        $model = Images::find()
        ->joinWith('product')
        ->where(['id' => $id])
        ->one();
        if (Yii::$app->user->can('updateFabricatorImages', ['brand_id' => $model->product->brand_id])) {
            Images::isArray($model);
            if ($model->delete()) {
                return $this->redirect(["products/view/?id=$model->product_id"]);
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new ForbiddenHttpException('Вам не разрешено производить данное действие.');
        }
```

Comment: `->andWhere(['id' => 'product_id'])` Что это? Строка равна строке?

Comment: @robertobadjo, также надо найти запись из таблицы `product`, у которой должно быть `'id' => 'product_image->id'. если бы я знал как правильно, я бы не задавал вопрос. дополнил вопрос, если вам интересно, что я подразумеваю.

Comment: @robertobadjo, не совсем верная формулировка, скорее "где значение поля записи равно строке". или это тоже оформляется как-то по-другому?

Comment: Cвязь `products` покажите

Comment: @robertobadjo, добавил к вопросу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$model = Images::find()
        ->joinWith('product')
        ->where(['product.id' => $id])
        ->asArray()
        ->one();
```

Answer (score 0):

Раз у Вас `hasOne` тогда связь лучше назвать `getProduct`

```
public function getProduct()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Products::className(), ['id' => 'product_id']);
}


$model = Images::find()
        ->joinWith(['product' => function ($q) {
             $q->from('product');
        }])
        ->where(['id' => $id])
        ->one();
```

Comment: разве этот запрос находит одну картинку, а не все?

Comment: Одна картинка, один продукт. Как все то? Если `one()`

Comment: хорошо. а как вернуть поле из связанной таблицы? $model->product->id?

Comment: `$model->product->{поле из модели Products}`

Comment: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous
The SQL being executed was: SELECT `product_image`.* FROM `product_image` LEFT JOIN `product` ON `product_image`.`product_id` = `product`.`id` WHERE `id`='233'

Comment: дополнил вопрос, видимо есть какие то нюансы.

Comment: Добавил в ответ

Comment: зачем нужен prod? у меня это просто переменная. или этот  запрос надо оставить? тогда какой смысл в джойне? с функцией и без та же ошибка, только джойнится таблица prod, которой нету, и product_image.product_id сравнивается с prod.id..SELECT `product_image`.* FROM `product_image` LEFT JOIN `product` `prod` ON `product_image`.`product_id` = `prod`.`id` WHERE `id`='233'.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83422/discussion-between-dasauser-and-robertobadjo).